# Custom Color action buttons, transparent card background,full screen custom layout notifications.Changing card color

Tags: wear-os

Custom Color action buttons, transparent card background,full screen custom layout notifications.Changing card color,ttf fonts for texts. changing text color . placing on different areas.

are these things possible ??
if its , why we cant use .
if its not how these peoples used these things

[image]

[image]

[image]

I really wanted to develop apps with these features. but current public api is really bad.
it provides nothing at all.but when we see screenshots new beautiful features exists.

I liked google wear and i see future about it . but when we compare with samsung galaxy gear or sony smartwatch, development in public goes slow.Maybe google devs doing things at the background,but if we don't have resources,how can developers can build apps for it.
I shared a basic app with my wishes and ideas.nobody answered about 2 days on google+ no one cares about posts on google+.public support of google wear for developers is sucks at the moment.

I need more customizable things for android wear to build apps.
but in current stage,i can't do much things with it.
i wish we had these features in screenshots below..

Comment: Hey, do u find a way to change the action button color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Those things are still not possible with the current preview release of AndroidWear.

If you look closely, you'll see that they've been using photoshop (or some other photo editing software)

Using [these templates](http://androiduiux.com/2014/03/19/android-wear-ui-design-kit-for-photoshop-0-1-free-download/) to design an app for Android Wear.

And for testing the design on the watch they used [Android Design Preview](https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidDesignPreview) which is a tool that lets you mirror a portion of your desktop to your device: